# QML_IMPORT_NAME seems to be an unknown variable, qml module not found

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to run [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) example with qt 5.15.1

When I declare QML_IMPORT_NAME, the variable seems to be unknown from qt (see the font's color
on the below screenshot) and when I import "com.mycompany.messaging" in my qml file, I have an error "QML module not found."

Edit:
After some investigations, the code runs as it should but I have this error in Qt Creator. If I want to edit qml file with the gui editor, I need to comment out all code related to the backend in text mode before otherwise, it fails to open the file.

What is the trick?

[image]

Comment: Did you add the QML_ELEMENT (or similar) macro to a C++ type?

Comment: Yes. :
class UiBackend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString userName READ userName WRITE setUserName NOTIFY userNameChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:

Comment: The example works for me. You said you're using "qt 15.1", which I assume is a typo and that you're actually using 5.15.1? Did you run qmake and rebuild after making the changes?

Comment: Yes, right 5.15.1, I did qmake and rebuild many times.... :(

Comment: Can you tell me if QML_IMPORT_CONFIG is coloured in your pro file ?

Comment: If fact, it compiles and works as it should but I have this error in Qt creator. If I want to edit qml file with the gui editor, I need to comment related code before... :(

Comment: I had same issue with 5.15.0, but did not tested 5.15.1. I used old style to register, because I did not found solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616252/qml-module-not-found-cpp-class-registration-with-new-qml-element-r

Comment: What do you mean by 'old style'?

Answer (score 1):

With [this](https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-type-registration-in-qt-5.15), I assumed I should have added

```
CONFIG += qmltypes
```

to .pro file. But since, I switched to cmake and did not find an equivalent, so I used the old method with:

```
qmlRegisterType<Person>("People", 1,0, "Person");
```

in main.cpp (see above link).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that is not fixed yet (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-24987).

The reason for the error is that QtCreator requires the generated .qmltypes and metatypes.json files next to the application binary.

A workaround for this is to add the following to your pro file:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) { 
    EXE_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/debug
} else { 
    EXE_DIR = $${OUT_PWD}/release
} 

CONFIG += file_copies 
COPIES += qmltypes metatypes 

qmltypes.files = $$files($${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}.qmltypes)
qmltypes.path = $${EXE_DIR} 

metatypes.files = $$files($${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}_metatypes.json)
metatypes.path = $${EXE_DIR}
```